# login after hibernation flashes desktop briefly

Tags: suspend, 18.04, laptop, hibernate, logout

I wonder if the following function is possible.

When i close the lid, my laptop (hp elitebook 2540p) hibernates as expected. when i open the lid and push the powerbutton it boots to Ubuntu (18.04). but it flashes the current session briefly (it shows my current work on my desktop for 1sec) before a login dialog shows. Because i work with privacy sensitive information this is not welcome.

My wish is that when i get the laptop out of hibernation, when the screen comes back on, it brings me to the login screen and doesn't show the desktop briefly. BUT i don't want the current session to end.

My search on askubuntu found me

[Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 - last screen flashes when waking up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/694455/ubuntu-gnome-15-10-last-screen-flashes-when-waking-up)
and
[Computer logout after closing the lid](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121591/computer-logout-after-closing-the-lid/1045958?noredirect=1#comment1706015_1045958).

Both offer no solution

thanks in advance

EDIT: it's a known bug in launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1532508

somebody knows a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: for me using Wayland [as suggested](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1532508/comments/20) instead of Xorg resolves the issue.

> On the login screen, you should be able to select "Ubuntu on Wayland" by clicking on the settings icon, next to the login button.

[18.04: How to get Wayland back after upgrade to 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1033004/477026)