# Ubuntu 20.04 Admin password flashes briefly when switching users

Tags: password, gui

Thinkpad 530 (2013)
Ubuntu 20.04

Admin user + 2 limited users, using the GUI

When switching from admin user to one of the other users, the admin password briefly flashes and can easily be read. This happens when one of the users has previously selected the "show password" (eye) icon in the password field.

I'm also experiencing the issue in this question: https://askubuntu.com/a/1056240/445044
(TL;DR - glimpses of another user's session are visible when coming out of hibernation)

I have done the switch to Wayland mentioned in this issue, which solved some other graphical glitchiness I was experiencing, but it didn't solve the above issues. I've scoured all my usual sources for solutions to this, but have not seen this exact problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please file a bug report for this issue.  The admin password should not be displayed in plain text. Your bug report should clearly explain --step-by-step-- how others can duplicate this issue using a 20.04 LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment or a fresh stock 20.04 install.